# Determine the number of digits in $4^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a natural number. How can we determine the number of digits in $4^n$?

For example $4^{20}$ has $13$ digits.

Comment: Consider taking a logarithm of base 10. What value do you receive for 10, 100, 1000? Could give some hints about 'digits' and how they relate to logarithms.

Comment: Hint: We have $4^{n} = 10^{(\log_{10} 4) n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to find a function $f$ with the property

$$ 10^{f(n)-1} \leq 4^n < 10^{f(n)} $$

Once you express what you want in the form of an equation, it's somewhat clearer how to solve for $f$!

---

Maybe it would help to write it instead as

$$ f(n) = m \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad  10^{m-1} \leq 4^n < 10^m $$

so that you can express the problem as solving for $m$, rather than solving for $f(n)$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: For a real number $r$, how many digits are in $10^r$ (before the decimal point)?

Can you write $4^n$ as $10^r$ for some $r$? (Hint: Logarithm).